# react native GeoLocation null reference error

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I am using the below code to try to get my current location:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
        let region = {
            latitude:       position.coords.latitude,
            longitude:      position.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta:  0.00922*1.5,
            longitudeDelta: 0.00421*1.5,
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        }
        this.onRegionChange(region, region.latitude, region.longitude);
    });
}
```

And I am getting:

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean abi26_0_0.com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap.hasKey(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Which is triggering on this line:

```
this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
```

Is there something I need to import for this to work maybe?   I can't find anything online about this.

Comment: Did you create your project using `react-native init`? If so, did you [do all the required configurations](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#configuration-and-permissions)?

Comment: I created the project using create-react-native-app.  I am not sure how this makes the syntax of that particular line incorrect.

Comment: Not sure what else you guys need from me to get some help with this one.  Would the entire class code help?    Also @Michael Cheng, that guide you linked I have seen before but it lists iOS and Android development.  I am using neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally nailed it after many hours of searching.

If you are using CRNA, like me (create-react-native-app was the way you built your app), you need to fulfill all parts of the function call.   These are (success, error, options).    The code below is how to fulfill all these parts and remove this error.

```
componentDidMount() {
this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
  (position) => {
    this.setState({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      error: null,
    });
  },
  (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000, distanceFilter: 10 },
);
}
```

Comment: More than one year later, this saved me! Thank you!! You should mark this answer as solved.

Comment: Hah, happy to have helped ;)